# Schengen Visa without a valid H1B Stamp

Tags: usa, schengen, schengen-visas

I am planning to travel to Amsterdam on the 22nd of December.

Before that, I plan to head to my home country to get my visa stamped (21st November - 12th December). As I would just have a week after I return to the USA before I leave for Amsterdam. I wanted to apply for my Schengen Visa now. I emailed the Consulate and they didn't give me a straight forward answer. What do you think are my chances to get the visa now.